# Problem installing ROS 2 Unable to locate package ros-foxy-desktop

Tags: installation, ros, ros2

I am trying to install ROS2 foxy following the tutorial (https://docs.ros.org/en/foxy/Installation/Ubuntu-Install-Debians.html)

However, when I arrive to the part of:

```
sudo apt install ros-foxy-desktop
```

I receive the following message

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package ros-foxy-desktop
```

I am trying to install it in Ubuntu 20.04 64 bits

Comment: Hard to say without more information. Possible you got an error on one of the earlier install steps?

Comment: Yes, I installed Ubuntu 22.04 instead of 20.04.